# write a program to create a new list such that the new list should contain odd numbers from the first list and even numbers from the second list

Tags: python

```py
list1 = [10, 20, 25, 30, 35]
list2 = [40, 45, 60, 75, 90]
def is_odd(num,list1):
  for num in list1:
     if num % 2 != 0:
         print(num, end=" ")
def is_even(num,list2):
  for num in list2:
      if num % 2 == 0:
         print(num, end=" ") 
list3=[is_odd(num,list1)  or is_even(num,list2)]           
print(list3)
```

I get this output: `25 35 40 60 90 [None]`
I want to get
result list: `[25, 35, 40, 60, 90]`

Comment: `list3=[is_odd(num,list1)  or is_even(num,list2)]`: Name `num` isn't defined here. Python can't run this.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `[None]` because the `print` function returns `None`. Instead of printing, in the `is_odd` or `is_even` function, you should return the numbers and append it into `list3`.

```
def is_odd(list1):
  temp = []
  for num in list1:
     if num % 2 != 0:
         temp.append(num)
  return temp

def is_even(list2):
  temp = []
  for num in list2:
      if num % 2 == 0:
        temp.append(num)
  return temp

list1 = [10, 20, 25, 30, 35]
list2 = [40, 45, 60, 75, 90]
list3 = []
list3 += is_odd(list1)
list3 += is_even(list2)  
print(list3)
```

Comment: can u help me with the code ?

Comment: @WaelTabbara let me know if that's what you expect.

Comment: yes thank you so much u just need to print it and it works